# How to add a comment with Nokogiri Builder

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

How do I add a `<!-- blahblah -->` comment to XML with Nokogiri's Builder?

I want to have something like:

```
<root>
  <!--blahblah-->
  <child/>
</root>
```

I try something like this:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.comment('blahblah')
    xml.child
  }
end
```

But that gives me:

```
<root>
  <comment>blahblah</comment>
  <child/>
</root>
```

Comment: I found the solution. Use xml.<<('<!--blahblah-->') instead of xml.comment

Comment: I have created [a bug report](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/625) for this; according to the documentation [`Builder#comment`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-comment) should create a comment.

Comment: @Phrogz Not a bug, just the docs are more up to date than the released gem (which is a refreshing change I guess): https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/commit/1acc7366372f7c2c186368fd5f13a1d9a96fef39. Works as advertised with current git master.

Comment: @matt Nice find! (Confirmed in later discussions on my erroneous report.) I've updated my answer below and also included a monkeypatch based on the future implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around [this <strike>bug</strike> documented future feature not present in the current release](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/625) by using [`Builder#<<`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-3C-3C) as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml << '<!--blahblah-->'
    xml.child
  }
end

puts xml.doc.root.to_xml
#=> <root>
#=>   <!--blahblah-->
#=>   <child/>
#=> </root>
```

Alternatively, you can monkeypatch in your own version of the future method:

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Builder
  def comment(string)
    insert Nokogiri::XML::Comment.new( doc, string.to_s )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [V1.6.8](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/commit/1acc7366372f7c2c186368fd5f13a1d9a96fef39) the `comment`-option is supported, you don't need the work around with `<<`.

If you need a comment-tag you can use `comment_` (with underscore in the end).

Example:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root { 
    xml.comment 'My comment' 
    xml.comment_ 'My comment-tag' 
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <!--My comment-->
  <comment>My comment-tag</comment>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, it might be obvious but as xml.comment creates a XML comment now, if you have to create an element `<comment>` you must use

```
  xml << "<comment>#{comment}</comment>"
```

It just happened to me. Thanks for hinting at the << method.